# Trait implementation with type guard makes conflicting implementation error

Tags: rust

This rust code makes error. But I don't understand why.

```rust
trait CanFoo1 {}

trait CanFoo2 {}

struct Bar1;
impl CanFoo1 for Bar1 {}

struct Bar2;
impl CanFoo2 for Bar2 {}

trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl<T: CanFoo1> Foo for T { // <-- first implementation here (but <T: CanFoo1> includes Bar1 only)
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Foo for CanFoo1");
    }
}

impl<T: CanFoo2> Foo for T { // <-- conflicting implementation (but <T: CanFoo2> includes Bar2 only)
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Foo for CanFoo2");
    }
}
```

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:21:1
   |
15 | impl<T: CanFoo1> Foo for T {
   | -------------------------- first implementation here
...
21 | impl<T: CanFoo2> Foo for T {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

`<T: CanFoo1>` includes Bar1 only and `<T: CanFoo2>` includes Bar2 only; I think it should be..
But the code makes error. Why? Does *type guard* not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing says that a type cannot implement both traits:

```
struct Example;
impl CanFoo1 for Example {}
impl CanFoo2 for Example {}
```

Now which implementation of `Foo` should be used for `Example`? Both are equally valid.

The implementations do indeed conflict for a type that implements both traits, and Rust cannot rule out the possibility of such a type existing.